# How do I get names for devices connected to my hotspot?

Tags: ios, tethering

Once I turn on a hotspot in Settings > Personal Hotspot, on iOS, and a device connects, a blue banner at the top of the screen appears with the number of connected devices.  I would like to see the hostname and any other associated information about the devices connected. Where could I find this information?

Comment: Answer to the question: Unfortunately no GUI exists in iOS for finding details about connected devices to the wireless hotspot (i.e. tethered devices). You can use a network scanner app to find connected devices, but it is not fool proof as it will only find devices that actively respond. Usually you'll only be able to find the MAC address and the IP-address given to the unit.

Comment: Nice save @jksoegaard - answer away officially now that the hold is released here

Answer (score 11):

With a network scanner app like Net Analyzer running on your iPhone, you can see who’s connected.

[image]

BlackMagic is my iPhone 7 - the host. The other two devices are Toshiba Flashair Cards connected to my personal hotspot.

Comment: I found that if you have to turn off wifi, while using this app, it's much easier to get the hotspot connected devices.

Answer (score 3):

While you can't see a current list of what is connected to your iphone's personal hotspot, you can goto Settings/Cellular/go down to the CELLULAR DATA section and click Personal Hotspot that has a Data amount next to it, and you will see a list of each device and the amount of data they have used on the hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no GUI exists in iOS for finding details about connected devices to the wireless hotspot (i.e. tethered devices). You can use a network scanner app to find connected devices, but it is not fool proof as it will only find devices that actively respond. Usually you'll only be able to find the MAC address and the IP-address given to the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Setting>Tap on the name of your Hot spot and you'll see the names  of the devices connected  you can then click on the names of the connected devices to remove them once you log into your iCloud account.

Comment: Check your answer again please - this no longer appears to be the case (if ever it was)

Comment: This was how we could determine who was connected  and could disconnect them for many years on IOS. Apparently Apple removed the interface within the last few years because I had need to use it about four years ago and it worked then.